# how to send multiple response in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a signin method in my nodejs which responds to frontend(reactjs) with user information such as email and password upon successful login. Now I have implemented JWT as well. So after signin, node will also send token to the client. But I don't know how to it. How can I send two responses at the same time? It is only sending the user info.

Node:

server.js

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => { signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt, jwt)});
```

signin.js

```
const handleSignin = (req, res, db, bcrypt, jwt) => {
  const {
    email,
    password
  } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json('Incorrect form submission');
  }
  db.select('email', 'hash').from('login')
    .where('email', '=', email)
    .then(data => {
    const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, data[0].hash);
    if (isValid) {
      return db.select('*').from('users')
        .where('email', '=', email)
        .then(user => {
        jwt.sign({
          user
        }, 'secretkey', {
          expiresIn: '1000s'
        }, (err, token) => {
          res.json(user[0]);
          res.send({
            token
          })
        })
      })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get user'))
    } else {
      res.status(400).json('wrong credentials')
    }
  })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('wrong credentials'))
}

module.exports = {
  handleSignin: handleSignin
}
```

Comment: That looks like an invalid code. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Combine the two responses into one. One request -> one response.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Pls review my updated post.

Comment: You can not send response more than once in any programming language rather than only NodeJS instead you can combine `res.json({user: user[0], token: token})`

Comment: @TedKhi Looks good.

Comment: I tried combining it. But it breaks signin method that is used in frontend (when receives user info)
 and I cannot login. Also, is this how we send Token to client via res.json and not res.send?

Comment: You obviously have to adapt your front end code to the new response. That's trivial though - just take the apropriate object's property you receive there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of res.json(user[0]); and res.send({token}); You can do like this res.json({user:user[0], token: token});

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers. Instead please click the "edit" button below your answer and then modify the answer as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending responses two times like below

```
  res.json(user[0]);
      res.send({
        token
      })
```

You will not get the 2nd response which is `token` because the program will send the first response and will consider its job done.

You can send multiple responses in one go by making an array of responses. And at client side just iterate the response to get your required key parameter.

```
response.json({user : user[0] , token : token , anyVariable : AnyData ... })
```